# "В далекой, далекой галактике"

Tags: орфография

Все мы знаем знаменитую фразу: "Давным давно, в далекой, далекой галактике...". Но почему "далекой, далекой" тут пишется через запятую, а не через дефис? Ведь тут явное усиление качества. Или это просто калька с английского написания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Устно на этот вопрос было бы ответить легче. Просто прочитать "далекой-далекой" и "далекой, далекой". Попробуйте сами и почувствуйте разницу. 
А вот как в правилах: запятая при повторяющихся словах ставится. если повторение обозначает высокую степень признака. причем каждое из повторяющихся слов имеет логическое ударение. (Вот, и здесь ссылка на интонацию!)